# Delete repeated value containing lines after keeping the first line

Tags: perl

I have a tab separated large file like this:

input.txt

```
a   b   c
s   t   e
a   b   c
f   q   y
r   e   x
```

to delete the repeated lines (rows) in this file, i use:

```
my %seen;
my @lines;

while (<>) {
    my @cols = split /\s+/;
    unless ($seen{$cols[0]}++) {
        push @lines, $_;
    }
}

print @lines;
```

the output here is:

```
a   b   c
s   t   e
f   q   y
r   e   x
```

Now if I want to delete those lines too that contain repeted values (means: that value once appear anywhere in upper rows/columns, here "e") and keep only the uppermost value containing line, please suggest what will be the most preffered approach keeping in mind that my input file is very large with many columns and rows.

model output that I want for the above input.txt would be:

```
a   b   c
s   t   e
f   q   y
```

Thank you

Comment: `split /\s+/` is almost never correct. You usually want `split ' '` ( a single literal space ) or just `split`, because that is the default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I wrote in my comments, `split /\s+/` is very rarely correct

And the solution you have mishandles lines with duplicate fields

It's also more efficient to replace `grep` with `any` from the core `List::Util` module

I suggest that you store the fields of each line in a hash `%cols`, like this

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use List::Util 'any';

my ( @lines, %seen );

while ( <DATA> ) {

    my %cols = map { $_ => 1 } split;

    push @lines, $_ unless any { $seen{$_}++ } keys %cols;
}

print for @lines;

__DATA__
a   b   c
p   p   p
p   q   r
s   t   e
a   b   c
f   q   y
r   e   x
```

#### output

```
a   b   c
p   p   p
s   t   e
```

Even this may not be what you want, as the line `f q y` is omitted because `q` has already been "seen" in the omitted line `p q r`. You will have to clarify the required behaviour in this situation

Answer (score 4):

You also need to iterate over the `@cols` and examine every item instead of just the first one, `$cols[0]`.
You need something like

```
unless ($seen{$cols[0]}++ || $seen{$cols[1]}++ || $seen{$cols[2]}++ ...) {
    push @lines, $_;
}
```

Of course that would be bad style and impossible if you don't know the number of columns in advance.

I would do it with [`grep`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html):

```
my %seen;
my @lines;

while (<DATA>) {
    my @cols = split /\s+/;
    unless ( grep { $seen{$_}++ } @cols ) {
        push @lines, $_;
    }
}

print @lines;


__DATA__
a   b   c
s   t   e
a   b   c
f   q   y
r   e   x
```

Output:

```
a   b   c
s   t   e
f   q   y
```

`grep` processes the code between the curlies `{ $seen{$_}++ }` for each element in the list `@cols` and returns (in scalar context) the number of items that evaluated to true.

It's not the fastest approach because it always iterates over the whole array (even if the first evaluation would be sufficient for your particular test). But give it a try; perhaps it's fast enough for you.

Comment: The code between the curlies is called a BLOCK, and is essentially a full anonymous sub. If you want to have it a little bit faster, you can use [`first` from List::Util](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::Util#first) instead of `grep`, which will stop iterating after the first match. But quite honestly you'd need a lot of columns and values for this to make a difference.

Comment: Golfed a little: `$ perl -awe 'print unless grep { $seen{$_}++ } @F' input.txt`

Comment: This won't work if the same value appears twice in a line. The second time it is tested it will already have been "seen" earlier in the line.

Comment: @Borodin Nicely spotted. I haven't thought about that. Depending on their needs, the OP should consider your solution.

Comment: Just a note -- the pattern `' '` in `split` uses any amount of any white space, so it is the same as `/\s+/`. Also, it is the default so here you can say `split`. Comes handly for picking values from the list, for example, `(split)[N]`. Lots of nice uses.  It is quite liberating once you get used to it.

Comment: @zdim `' '` and `/\s+/` aren't exactly the same: `split(/\s+/, ' col1')` gives **two** elements (empty string plus `"col1"`), but `split(' ', ' col1')` gives only **one** because it also eliminates empty fields at the beginning. I don't like this _side effect_ because it's not clear and anybody not familiar with `split`'s manpage would expect `' '` to split at _exactly one space_ but, surprise, surprise, it does more than it pretends.

Comment: @PerlDuck  Yes, you are right, using manual regex patterns keeps spaces while the default prunes them.  I know what you mean, that's why I had used the explicit `/\s+/` for a long time.  However, for me the relieving part is that `' '` is _the default_, even as it is surprising.  It'd be nice to be able to escape the need to know (the often picky) details. The only downside to me is that I often have to make a note in posts here :). Anyway, I won't bug you with this particular thing again :).

Comment: Hey, @zdim, you didn't bug me at all! :-) I think the both of us are experienced Perl programmers and we know `split` in and out. I really love Perl but sometimes (in very rare cases) I just don't like its built-in magic when apparently obvious code does something unexpected. And `split(' ')` is one such thing. When I write code at work and use `' '` then I often spend a comment when it's likely that my code is read by colleagues not so familiar with `split`.

Comment: @PerlDuck Well, yes, I know (I hope so) -- it was partly a joke.  The other part -- sometimes people are just unaware of details, when it may be good to bring them up. But if they do know and have their preference then there is no need to mention it.  As for the little details, I view Perll still as a low-level language. Yes, there are high-level tools and one can write fairly clean code but there are always little things to be aware of.  I like that, for me it's a good thing.  You _can_ go low, you can stay high. (I like C++ in a similar way. There you _build_ high-level tools.)